# Simple onclick page loader

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I made this really basic startup page in HTML that has images that reference websites. Is there a way to add a loader after the user clicks on the image then the loader goes away when the website comes up? I am trying to give users something to look at while a website loads. Below is a sample href line that I use.

```
<a href="https://Website.com"><img border="0" alt="Image" src="logo.gif"></a>
```

I found this onclick script online but I do not know how to add it to my startup page. Can anyone help me put these together? Where should I place the line 'onclick="myFunction()?"'Thank you!

```
 onclick="myFunction()"

 <script>
 var myVar;

 function myFunction() {
 myVar = setTimeout(showPage, 3000);
 }

 function showPage() {
 document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: Isn't the new page replacing the current page? The anchor you show in the question seems to be a standard link to another page/site. If so, you wouldn't need to worry about hiding any "loading..." image, it would disappear automatically when the current page unloads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of something you need,.

**A loader will be displayed when you click on the button, and disappears after the website loads.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
   var myVar;
 $( "#myDiv" ).click(function() {
   myFunction(this);
});

 function myFunction(div) {
 $("#loader").toggle();
 $(div).toggle();

 }

   
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a id="myDiv" href="https://Website.com">Click me</a>
<div id="loader" style="display:none;background:green;padding:150px">This is a loader</div>


</body>
</html>
```

[**Here is a working DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/aJzcGZ2LJng5heTshoiM?p=preview)

Comment: Your snippet doesn't work. No need for the inline `onclick` attribute when you are binding a click handler with jQuery.

Comment: @nnnnnnn, `OnClick` in html was written in overlook, but my snippet is working fine. you can even check the DEMO.

Comment: Well sure, it works now that you've edited it. Why do you have the timeout? The new page will replace the current one, so there's no need to manually hide the loader, and in any case if you hide it after a fixed time the user may be left with several seconds of nothing before the other page loads.

Comment: thanks, yes that too has a point, I gave the answer to make him understand how that code actually works. It can be removed as the page redirects to a new page. anyway removed it. Thanks.

Comment: Can I reuse the function if I need to add more websites?

Comment: yes you can. since the loader is same in the whole page, you can add the parent Id of the div so that the whole div gets hidden and could display loader

Comment: @kcd, check the updated answer. you can even pass the div reference.

Comment: Nice. Thank you, correct me if I'm wrong, the function is like a method, right? If so, I think I understood what it is doing, I appreciate the explanation!

Comment: yes exactly, a `function` is a `method` in javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You may refer to the following link, it properly explains, how it is too be done. 
http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/learn-asynchronous-image-loading-javascript

Comment: Link-only answers are frowned upon at Stack Overflow, but in any case the OP isn't trying to load an image, they seem to be loading (or navigating to) another page.